# Will drywall mud bond to oil-based primer?

Tags: paint, primer, drywall-mud

Will drywall mud bond to oil primer?  We just removed a recessed ironing board from a wall in the kitchen.  The surrounding walls have oil paint, and we want to prime that surrounding area before mudding to create a good bond between the mud and the existing oil paint.
We have oil primer on hand and prefer to use it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will work fine for you, just give the recommended dry time as if you were topcoating with water based paint. I recall 2 days for some finishes.

Anyway, I would lightly sand the area to give the drywall mud a bit of a "tooth" onto the surface and smooth out any rough spots before applying mud.

Comment: This answered our question and we will proceed with using the oil primer.